# logging the exceptions to a file

Tags: java, logging, exception, log4j

I have a stand alone class. I have to provide a logging mechanism for this file to log all the process taking place including exceptions. Later this would get integrated with a jar or so. What is the best logging mechanism which would be compatible even after integration. Since mine is just a class file which is not included in a jar, is it possible to use log4J? more suggestions welcome.

Comment: yes, you will need to add the log4j jar to the classpath of your project for that.

Comment: i added log4j to classpath and added static variable  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(sample.class); in my class and used log.debug("log me");, i get this exception:"log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager)."
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) as an implementation of the generic slf4j framework. Note that log4j is an implementation of slf4j as well and this mean that if you program to the slf4 interface you can exchange logback and log4j by just replacing one jar with the other. Go with the first baby steps and note the generic imports of this introduction [link](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html). With logback you can instruct your app where to locate the configuration file with the following: `-Dlogback.configurationFile=path/filename.ext`

The exception that you're receiving (described in your comment) means that you probably did not configure log4j or that your app couldn't locate the configuration file.

Writing your own logger class or using the one provided by the util package is prob ably not a good idea..

Comment: where do i put the property file? mine just has a class file and jar files in the classpath.

Comment: Just run this System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); and the system will tell you where to put it. You should be able to change the location with some configuration options like the one in my answer for logback. Are you using a property file or a xml with log4j? In the latter case do not forget the xsd file as well. Still, try logback!

Comment: Thanks Gevorg. I have a property file like this log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CA
 
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppenderlog4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n      Now this writes log to the console. I want to write them to a specific file to my C:// or something like that. Where should i spencify that?

Comment: You need to specify a FileAppender (instead or in addition to the Console one). I'm not super familiar with log4j configuration but you can find an example here: http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-file-appender-example-1.html Also, it might be worth it to invest some time reading the documentation since there are tons of useful options embedded in these logging frameworks (RollingFiles, Filters, Compression, SiftingAppenders(in LogBack).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gevorg. I was able to get some online help too. Thanks much for your time. I appreciate it. Now i am able to log to a file in my c://.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.util.logging.Logger`, it's part of java since 1.4.2 (at least).

But the most appropriate thing you can do is using the logging framework you know you are going to use when your class will be integrated in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the use of a static class here, which you can define by yourself. For example something like this:

```
class Logger {
    public Logger() {
        //you can create/open a log file here
    }
    public static void log(String message, int messageType) {
        //write to the file, or whatever you want to do with the message
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Call new Logger(); somewhere during the startup of your program. Now you can call anywhere

```
Logger.log(message);
```

In my case this was more than sufficient, though very simple. I am not familiar with libraries like log4j, which may include more features.

Comment: "Implement your own logging framework" is rarely the correct answer these days.  Yes it will work.  Downstream integrators will curse your name for eternity.  My recommendation is to leverage the logging built into the JVM or pick one of the tried and true frameworks like log4j.